# If $\int^{\pi}_0 x f (\sin x) dx = k \int^{\pi/2}_0 f (\sin x) dx$, find $k$.

Tags: integration

> **Problem** : If $\int^{\pi}_0 x f (\sin x) dx = k \int^{\pi/2}_0 f (\sin x) dx$, find $k$.
>
> **Solution** : Period of sine function is $2 \pi$

I don't know whether we can use the period of this function to solve this problem.

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but I imagine the person who did did it because your title contains all the relevant information about the question and the body of the post doesn't contribute much.

Comment: Why did this get a down vote?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $ I := \int\limits_0^\pi x f(\sin x)\ dx $. By the substitution $ u \mapsto \pi - x $, we arrive at $$I =  \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\pi - u\right) f\left(\sin\left(\pi - u\right)\right) \ du = \int\limits_0^\pi \left(\pi - u\right)f(\sin u)\ du $$Hence, $$ 2I = \int_0^\pi \left(u + \left(\pi - u\right)\right)f(\sin u) \ du = 2\pi \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(\sin u) \ du $$ Hence, the answer is that $ k = \pi $.

Comment: Can we use $f(sin ({\pi/2}- x) = f (sin x)$. I think $sin ({\pi/2}- x)= cosx$

Comment: You're right. I'll fix the post.

Comment: Now u= $\pi -x $ when $x=0$ then $u= \pi$ and when $x= \pi$ then u should be $0$ also $du =- dx$ I get it

Comment: @JonClaus I have a question: in your final integral $2\pi \int_0^\frac{\pi}{2} f(\sin u) \ du$, how did you factor the $2$ out of the integral and make the upper bound of the integral $\pi/2$?

Comment: $ \sin x $ is symmetric about $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ so the integral from $ 0 $ to $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ has the same value as the integral from $ \frac{\pi}{2} $ to $ \pi $.

Comment: @JonClaus Ah that makes sense. Clever.

Comment: @rst, after the substitution the bottom limit becomes $ \pi $, the upper limit becomes $ 0 $, and $ dx $ becomes $ -du $. Then you can reverse the two limits by canceling the negation.

Comment: In general, $ \displaystyle \int_a^b f(x) \ dx = \int_a^b f(a + b - x) \ dx $ precisely by that logic.

Comment: @JonClaus Yeah, I realized it after posting the comment. Thats why  wrote"I get it"

Comment: We can also see last step by the formula $\int^{2a} _0 f dx=2\int^a _0 f dx$ if $f(2a-x)=f(x)$

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the given equation is true regardless of the unknown function $f$. Then, to simplify calculations, choose a simple function such as $f(x)=1$. Then we obtain:
$$ \begin{align*}
\int_0^{\pi} x dx &=  k\int_0^{\pi/2} dx \\
\left[\dfrac{x^2}{2} \right]_0^{\pi} &=  k\left[x \right]_0^{\pi/2} \\
\dfrac{\pi^2}{2} &=  k\left[\dfrac{\pi}{2} \right] \\
k &= \pi
\end{align*} $$

Comment: This can be a useful strategy for multiple choice questions.

Comment: Depending on the context for the OP, that assumption for $f$ may require more justification.

Comment: @AndréNicolas A very helpful observation!

Comment: Well, above assumption is not necessary